# PTIJ: How did the chickens get involved?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In explaining the various obligations on Purim, the codifiers insist that more than just men are obligated [because](https://www.sefaria.org/topics/af-hen-hayu-be-oto-ha-nes?sort=Relevance&tab=sources) "af Hen hayu b'oto hanes", even the hens were involved with the same miracle*.

How were female chickens affected by the miracles of Purim (or any other holiday which employs this same rule to obligate hens)?

---

*no, the text does not say "ofe hen" or "af/nose of a hen" or "auto hanes" or "b'oto hens" as those would all be ridiculous!

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 9):

It's a very simple answer.

As the Gemara in Bava Basra writes in [119b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.119b.13?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi)

> אֶלָּא מִתּוֹךְ שֶׁצִּדְקָנִיּוֹת הֵן, נַעֲשָׂה לָהֶן נֵס
>
> Rather because they were righteous hens, a miracle was performed for them

Answer (score 2):

It says הן over 10,000 times in chazal. Also over 400 times in Tanach.
If it means hen, there's way bigger problems to deal with.